# How to compute new coordinates after rotation?

Tags: svg, matrix, transform

Applying a translate-transformation (`matrix(1 0 0 1 tx ty)`) I get the new coordinates by just calculating `x(new) = x + tx, y(new) = y + ty`.

Applying a scale-transformation (`matrix(sx 0 0 sy 0 0)`) I just multiply:`x(new) = x * sx, y(new) = y * sy`.

Now here's my question: How can I do this for a rotation (with a rotation center other than 0,0)?

In general: How to compute the new coordinates one gets after applying a matrix (a b c d e f) in SVG?

Comment: a rotation centre other than 0 0 is basically a translate, a rotate at 0,0 and a translate in the opposite direction to the initial translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up some math.

It's a matrix-vector-multiplication. For SVG that means:

`matrix(a b c d e f)` corresponds to

```
x(new) = a*x + c*y + e

y(new) = b*x + d*y + f
```